# Search Ruby on Rails Database for Key Value Pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

Hey all i'm getting hung up on how to search a database for a specific key pair.  What i'm doing is sending a combine array of objects that represent data not sent for that user for the day.  Here is the basic logic

Unless the database contains the object_id and user_id 
  insert it into the array

The association is many objects to many users.

Is their a way to search the table cases_users so that it is a query like this

unless cases_users.contains? {object_id, user_id}
  objectarray.push(object_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
objectarray.push(object_id) unless User.find_by_object_id_and_user_id(object_id, user_id)
```

Comment: Thats it!  i knew their is was an easier rails way than iterating through both of them.